# Is `reddit` against crawler for moving to next page?

Tags: scrapy, reddit

I am using `python scrapy` to crawl `reddit`. But I found the response html from scrapy doesn't have the button `next page` so I can't move to the next page in my spider code. Is this something caused by `reddit` or is there anything wrong about how I use `scarpy`? Below is the code I currently have in python:

```
class RedditNetflixSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'reddit_netflix'
    allowed_domains = ['www.reddit.com/r/movies/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/']

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.css('h3::text').extract()
        votes = response.css('.voteButton[aria-label="upvote"] + div::text').extract()
        odd_votes = votes[::2]
        comments = response.css('a[rel="nofollow"] span::text').extract()
        for item in zip(titles, odd_votes, comments):
            scraped_info = {
                'title': item[0],
                'vote': item[1],
                'comments': item[2].replace(' comments', '').strip(),
            }
            yield scraped_inf
```

Comment: Reddit seems have their [official api](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/). Do you have any reason not to use it ?

Comment: because it requires `oauth` authentication.